# Adobe Illustrator: Can I temporarily hide highlighting of selected paths?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, stroke, workflow, outline

Sometimes when working on a piece, you want to browse through various options, styles, effects, etc. and experiment until you find the right one.

The problem is this thin blue line (and sometimes the handles) that shows the path of the selected objects. Sometimes it's useful, but sometimes it just gets in the way.

It's not a huge issue, but it keeps cramping my workflow. Is there a way to hide it temporarily?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> Win to **Hide Edges**

Menu View → Show/Hide Edges

Comment: Thanks. So many options, I get lost in the menus sometimes.